# How to optimize a PostrgreSQL query and avoid using "NOT IN"?

Tags: postgresql

A newbie question for PostgreSQL. I have the following query in which I am trying to return a union of all records that fit the criteria of:

1. all dx marked chronic prior to tencounter,
2. all recurrent dx (i.e., a dx record that is marked treated more recent then any previous resolution, and
3. any dx record marked treated that has never been resolved

Is there a better way of doing this (perhaps using the WITH clause of PostgreSQL)?  I have read not to us "NOT IN" in PostgreSQL, so how better could this be done? How do you "optimize" this thing?

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_getactivedx(groupid character varying, tencounter timestamp without time zone)
   RETURNS SETOF view_dx AS
$BODY$

    select max(dx.recid) as recid, dx.cicd9, dx.cdesc, max( dx.tposted) as tposted, 
    bool_or(dx.resolved) as resolved, bool_or(dx.treated) as treated, bool_or(dx.chronic),
    dx.groupid 
        from dx 
    where dx.chronic = true 
    and dx.groupid = $1 
    and date_trunc('day',dx.tposted) <= date_trunc('day',$2)
    group by dx.cicd9, dx.cdesc, dx.groupid

    union


    select max(dx.recid) as recid, dx.cicd9, dx.cdesc, max( dx.tposted) as tposted, 
    bool_and(dx.resolved), bool_and(dx.treated), bool_and(dx.chronic), dx.groupid 
    from dx 
            join    (select cdesc, max(tposted) as tposted from dx  
                       where groupid =$1  and resolved = true and 
                       date_trunc('day',tposted) <=  date_trunc('day', $2)
                       group by cdesc) j 
              on (dx.cdesc = j.cdesc and dx.tposted > j.tposted) 
              where groupid = $1 and treated = true
              and date_trunc('day',dx.tposted)  <= date_trunc('day', $2)
              group by dx.cicd9, dx.cdesc, dx.groupid 

    union 

    select max(dx.recid) as recid, dx.cicd9, dx.cdesc, max( dx.tposted), 
       bool_and(dx.resolved), bool_and(dx.treated), bool_and(dx.chronic), dx.groupid 
              from dx 
              where dx.cdesc NOT IN
                (select cdesc from dx  
                       where groupid =$1  and resolved = true and 
                       date_trunc('day',tposted) <=  date_trunc('day', $2)
                       group by cdesc) 
             and groupid =$1 and treated = true and
              date_trunc('day',tposted)   <= date_trunc('day', $2)        
              group by dx.cicd9, dx.cdesc, dx.groupid

    order by tposted desc, treated desc, resolved desc, cdesc asc
```

Comment: `NOT IN` can be OK, you just have to think carefully about NULL, and an anti-join is often a better choice.

Comment: Closely related: [Select rows which are not present in other table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT IN` can be OK, you just have to think carefully about NULL, and an anti-join is often a better choice.

For any query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM t
WHERE col NOT IN (SELECT col2 FROM t2 WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL AND ...predicate...)
```

you can equivalently write:

```
SELECT ...
FROM t LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON (t.col = t2.col2 AND ...predicate...)
WHERE t2.col2 IS NULL;
```

which is called a "left anti-join".

PostgreSQL may well produce the same query plan for both.

Unless you know that your `NOT IN` use is causing performance issues for some reason, after proper checking with `explain analyze`, I strongly suggest just leaving it alone.

Comment: What is an "anti-join"? Sounds weird.

Answer (score 1):

Using `NOT EXISTS` is often more efficient than using `NOT IN`.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM B
  WHERE A.id = B.id
)
```